# In the latest linux kernel is it possible to write a loadable Linux Security Module (LSM), which can be loaded and unloaded using insmod and rmmod?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, linux-security-module

I am a beginner in the field of Linux kernel programming. I was studying Linux Security Modules (LSM). The references which I have seen (recent ones) especially this video [here](https://youtu.be/Y0QZpan5LbU), bakes the module written into the kernel itself, and then the entire compiled kernel is installed on say an Ubuntu machine.

I was thinking of writing a program, such that instead of making it into the kernel itself, I could load and unload it as per my need. (Especially to test the correctness of its functionality, easily).

The [video](https://youtu.be/Y0QZpan5LbU) which I have mentioned above makes use of `security_add_hooks` to bind our function to the security subsystem. But, using the mention of `security_add_hooks` and `LSM_HOOK_INIT` which in turn uses `security_hook_heads` struct, causes an issue when I try to make a `.ko` file for this module.

```
ERROR: modpost: "security_add_hooks" [security/my_test.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "security_hook_heads" [security/my_test.ko] undefined!
```

I can understand that `security_add_hooks` is a function and has not been exported for use by the modules. So, I tried to `EXPORT_SYMBOL(security_add_hooks)` so that my `.ko` file can use it.

But another issue arises. Regarding two `struct` definitions, `security_hook_heads` and `security_hook_list`. I simply don't know how to export them. I tried to write a statement `EXPORT_SYMBOL(security_hook_heads);` just after the corresponding struct definition as follows, in `lsm_hooks.h`:

```c
struct security_hook_heads {
    #define LSM_HOOK(RET, DEFAULT, NAME, ...) struct hlist_head NAME;
    #include "lsm_hook_defs.h"
    #undef LSM_HOOK
} __randomize_layout;

EXPORT_SYMBOL(security_hook_heads);
```

Corresponding to this I get the following error:

```
./include/linux/lsm_hooks.h:1601:15: error: ‘security_hook_heads’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 1601 | EXPORT_SYMBOL(security_hook_heads);
```

I don't fully understand the meaning of the error, but I feel it is trying to point out that exporting a symbol from a header file is not possible.

So, I could not figure out how to work out this approach. Is there any other easy method available?

I was going through a few old YouTube videos and [a few articles](https://github.com/node3/Linux-Security-Module/blob/master/pindown.c), where they make use of functions like `register_security` and `unregister_security`,  but I guess these functions are no longer there in the latest Linux kernel (6.0.0). [As was mentioned in the thread of the following few questions: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25589364/7571421), [see the comment to the answer for the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25591581/7571421), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172886/7571421)]

Comment: pretty sure AppArmor uses a loadable module. Check how it works.

Comment: @stark, I looked into the `lsm.c` file in the AppArmor folder in the security subsystem. I am using kernel 6.0.0, there on line `1205` they define an array of `struct security_hook_list` and uses `LSM_HOOK_INIT` to initialize that array, and `LSM_HOOK_INIT` is a macro which uses `security_hook_head`. Also, in the `apparmor_init(void)` function, on line `1899` they make use of `security_add_hooks` function, which is not exported, so I guess, that issue remains, I am facing, as far as I can understand from my knowledge. Please could you guide me further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in a module.

1. `security_add_hooks` is marked with `__init`.
2. It is linked into a special linker section (e.g. `.init.text`).
3. At a certain point in the *kernel* startup (see: `kernel_init`) it calls `free_initmem`.
4. After that, the memory occupied by these functions is reclaimed and can be used as ordinary memory.

So, by the time your module is loaded, `security_add_hooks` et. al. are long gone.

If you have to modify `security/security.c` to add `EXPORT_SYMBOL(security_add_hooks)`, then you are building a custom kernel. So, you might as well just bake your code into the kernel.